# File is not opening from Assets in Android

Tags: android, android-assets

I am trying to read images from Assets.In Assets i have been using a-z folders and these folders contains images with the starting name of folder like if there is folder named YImages
then images in this folder image's names are also starting with Y word.

I am using this function to get images from Assets:

```
        try {
        pics = Drawable
                .createFromStream(
                        getAssets().open(
                                imageFolder + wordString.get(index)
                                + ".jpg"), null);

        picture.setBackgroundDrawable(pics);
        picture.refreshDrawableState();


    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a space at your image path. `java.io.FileNotFoundException: yImages/ Year.jpg`
Try trimming the File name.

Answer (score 1):

Just change all the image file name with the small letters do not use the capital letter in image file name . i.e `badger_thumbnail.jpg`,`badge_thumbnail.jpg`,`year.jpg` like this. Also keep in mind that there is no space in your any image name.

Comment: WHY "no capital letter in image file name"?